# Unexpected Python TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw two lines, each works well when separated, but when I draw two at a time, then there's an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "2.py", line 99, in 
>       fspe2 = [fspe(t2,x) for t2 in t]  TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Full Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
from pylab import *

c = 2.998*10**10
hp = 6.626*10**-27
hb = 1.055*10**-27
kb = 1.381*10**-16
g = 6.673*10**-8
me = 9.109*10**-28
mp = 1.673*10**-24
q = 4.803*10**-10
sigT = 6.652*10**-25

p = 2.5
r014 = 1
E53 = 1
g42 = 1
delt12 =1
epsBR2 = 1
epseR1 = 1
DLG = 1 

r0 = r014*10**14
E0 = E53*10**53
g4 = g42*10**2.5
delt0 = delt12*10**12
epseR = epseR1*0.1
epsBR = epsBR2*0.01
n1 = 1.0
k = 0
DL = DLG*3.086*10**27

N0 = E0/(g4*mp*c**2)
SedL = (3*E0/(4*math.pi*n1*mp*c**2))**(1./3)
ttw = delt0/c  
ttn = SedL/(2*c*g4**(3./8))  
Reta = SedL/g4**(2./3)

def Gam3(t):
  if delt0 > SedL/(2*g4**(8./3)):
    return np.where(t<ttw,(SedL/delt0)**(3./8)*(4*t/ttw)**(-1./4),(SedL/delt0)**(3./8)*(4*ttw/ttw)**(-1./4)*(t/ttw)**(-7./16))
  else:
    return np.where(t<ttn,g4,g4*(t/ttn)**(-2./5))

def n3(t):
  if delt0 > SedL/(2*g4**(8./3)):
    return np.where(t<ttw,8*Gam3(t)**3*n1/g4,8*Gam3(ttw)**3*n1/g4*(t/ttw)**(-13./16))
  else:
    return np.where(t<ttn,7*n1*g4**2*(t/ttn)**-3,7*n1*g4**2*(t/ttn)**(-6./7))

def e3(t):
  if delt0 > SedL/(2*g4**(8./3)):
    return np.where(t<ttw,4*Gam3(t)**2*n1*mp*c**2,4*Gam3(ttw)**2*n1*mp*c**2*(t/ttw)**(-13./12))
  else:
    return np.where(t<ttn,4*g4**2*n1*mp*c**2,4*g4**2*n1*mp*c**2*(t/ttn)**(-8./7))

def Ne3(t):
  if delt0 > SedL/(2*g4**(8./3)):
    return np.where(t<ttw,N0*(t/ttw),N0)
  else:
    return np.where(t<ttn,N0*(t/ttn)**(3./2),N0)

gem = lambda t : epseR*e3(t)/(n3(t)*me*c**2)*(p-2)/(p-1)
BR  = lambda t : np.sqrt(8*math.pi*epsBR*e3(t))
gec = lambda t : 6*math.pi*me*c/(sigT*BR(t)**2*Gam3(t)*t)
num = lambda t : 3*q*BR(t)/(4*math.pi*me*c)*gem(t)**2*Gam3(t)
nuc = lambda t : 3*q*BR(t)/(4*math.pi*me*c)*gec(t)**2*Gam3(t)
Fmax = lambda t : Ne3(t)*math.sqrt(3)*q**3*BR(t)/(me*c**2)*Gam3(t)/(4*math.pi*DL**2)

def fspe(t,u):
  if num(t)<nuc(t):
    return np.where(u<num(t),(u/num(t))**(1./3)*Fmax(t),np.where(u<nuc(t),(u/num(t))**(-(p-1.)/2)*Fmax(t),(u/nuc(t))**(-p/2)*(nuc(t)/num(t))**(-(p-1.)/2)*Fmax(t)))*u
  else:
    return np.where(u<nuc(t),(u/muc(t))**(1./3)*Fmax(t),np.where(u<num(t),(u/nuc(t))**(-1./2)*Fmax(t),(u/num(t))**(-p/2)*(num(t)/nuc(t))**(-1.2)*Fmax(t)))*u

xmin = 2
xmax = 10
i = np.arange(xmin,xmax,0.01)
t = 10**i

plt.figure('God Bless: Lightcure')
plt.title(r'Lightcurve''\n2 Cases')
plt.xlabel(r'log t')
plt.ylabel(r'log Flux')

x = 10**10
fspe = [fspe(t1,x) for t1 in t] 
Lightcurve1 = [math.log10(a5) for a5 in fspe]
plt.plot(i,Lightcurve1,'.',label=r'$\nu=10^{10}$')

########################
## Strange thing happens!The above 4 sentences work well,
## why added the same statements, there's an Error?
x = 10**15
fspe2 = [fspe(t2,x) for t2 in t] 
### This place feedback--Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "1.py", line 94, in <module>
#    fspe2 = [fspe(t2,x) for t2 in t] 
#TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
Lightcurve2 = [math.log10(a6) for a6 in fspe2]
plt.plot(i,Lightcurve2,'>',label=r'$\nu=10^{15}$')
#######################

plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: also give the full error traceback

Comment: jesuslove@jesuslove-220s-series:~/matplotlib$ python 2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 99, in <module>
    fspe2 = [fspe(t2,x) for t2 in t] 
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
jesuslove@jesuslove-220s-series:~/matplotlib$

Comment: `fspe = [fspe(t1,x) for t1 in t]` line 91 you assign over your function with a list. How you correct that depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, God bless my friend!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traceback: literally, a way for you to trace a path from the error message back to the line that caused it. Python's error messages are usually very good, so take what it says at face value and follow it back. It'll even describe the path of function calls that produced this result, which serve as breadcrumbs.

1. `fspe2 = [fspe(t2,x) for t2 in t] TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`
2. Where did you call something? The only instance of it in that line is `fspe(t2,x)`.
3. What did it try to call? A `list`. Therefore, `fspe` is a `list` at that point.
4. Let's find out where `fspe` was assigned, searching for that term in your editor or IDE (or within this browser window).
5. `def fspe(t,u):` - Nope, that defines a function.
6. `fspe = [fspe(t1,x) for t1 in t]` - There's our culprit! You created a `list` involving the previously-defined `fspe` function, and then assigned it to the same name `fspe`, thus masking the function and making it inaccessible (and, if there were no more existing references to it, removed entirely by the garbage collector).
7. The fix is to give it a unique name, like `fspe3` or `fspe_calcs` or `fspe_list`.

Comment: Wow, you have explained this pretty well ! I learned very much from this ! Thank you very much, God bless my friend!

Answer (score 2):

You assign over the function `fspe` with a list on line 91.

```
fspe = [fspe(t1,x) for t1 in t]
```

I made a simple change

```
fspe_list = [fspe(t1,x) for t1 in t] 
Lightcurve1 = [math.log10(a5) for a5 in fspe_list]
```

that at least runs. Whether it does what you want I dont know.